# Subtract 5 minutes from a date value

Tags: mysql

I'm currently writing a snippet of code which will look through the database and see if any admins are currently online and show them on the side of the page as being online.

Every time a user browses through a page on my site (when they are logged in) it grabs the current time and updates a column called `lastseen`.

I have a role column that marks a user from an admin and what I want it to do is query the database for all the admins and check the `lastseen` column and if that time is within 5 minutes of the current time then output them to a row which I can then take and format later.

This is what I currently tried but nothing came back.

```
SELECT username, role, lastseen 
FROM database.accounts 
WHERE lastseen >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND role='admin'
```

I am storing `lastseen` as `date('Y-m-d H-i-s')` from PHP so it looks like this
`2017-02-18 16:07:42` in the database.

Comment: Sure 
`INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `role`, `email`, `regip`, `experience`, `level`, `rank`, `lastip`, `deleted`, `banned`, `regdate`, `lastlogindate`, `emailenabled`, `lastseen`, `reghash`, `active`, `hp`) VALUES ('0', 'Testuser', '$6$rounds=10000$wmknwubJ0IfllHl5$Vd25WbsNkxWzgz154i3tE8Z8uuJQuSHdCGIfIgDfvRTfOobpcPJ0G5kaW2OYgd29AtBGm9GLksyaQOklUIr92.', 'user', 'testme@localhost.net', '72.0.129.61', '250', '0', '0', '72.0.129.61', '0', '0', '2017-02-15 06:35:37', '2017-02-16 07:26:46', '1', '2017-02-16 02:27:13', '', '1', '2')`

may have dropped too much XD

Comment: Make sure that the timezone for PHP and MySQL are the same. Just to ensure, try to set the `lastseen` for an admin account to year 2018.

Comment: That actually worked, checking the MYSQL and PHP timezones now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is your datatype for `lastseen`, Your query seems correct , just try with

```
SELECT username, role, lastseen FROM database.accounts 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(lastseen, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND role='admin'
```

**Also make sure your PHP and MYSQL Server have same timezones**

Comment: Datatype for lastseen is datetime. I tried with that query but it still didn't return any results.

Comment: check your php and mysql timezones are synchronized or not